# Associations in New York City for travel

Tags: usa

I live in Normandy, France and I'm a 12th grade student. My region's government allows me to spend on summer vacations up to €3,500 to go abroad for 4 weeks if I join an association and go abroad for this association. I want to go to New York City, but I don't know what association to join, because I couldn't find associations on Google.

I love science, technology, languages. It would be great if someone who knows NYC can advise me about that or if you know where to find. I'm sorry if my post doesn't match with the "expatriates" category.

Thank you!

Comment: Am I right that what you mean by "join an association" is "volunteer for a non-profit" ?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Some information here : https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47943/is-volunteer-work-allowed-in-the-us-while-visiting-under-the-vwp-or-a-b1-b2-visa